# Python - Discord bot on ready send message to channel

Tags: python, bots, discord

I have problem creating simple python script which sends message to default channel when executed from terminal.

```
import discord

@bot.event
async def on_ready(ctx):
    print('Online')
    await ctx.send('Message sent!')


bot.run('MYTOKEN')
```

with this example I keep getting "ctx" is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the `on_ready` event should not receive any parameters. See the Minimal Bot documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot) and the on_ready documentation in the Event Reference [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready). If you want to send a message when the bot connects. You must first [get the channel object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) and then use the send method. You can find an example of getting a channel and sending a message in the FAQ section of the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-send-a-message-to-a-specific-channel)